# Vertex cover algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, graph-colorings

Given a graph $G(V, E)$, remove the vertex (or one of the vertices) with the highest cardinality from $G$ and put it in a list $L$. Repeat until in $G$ there are only vertices with cardinality $0$ (no edges in the graph).

Now, for each vertex $v$ of $L$, from the first to the last (first in first out), check if its edges, in the given graph, are covered by the vertices that are after $v$ in the list. If it is, remove $v$ from $L$, otherwise leave $v$ in $L$.

At the end the vertices of $L$ are a vertex cover of the given $G(V, E)$, but is it a minimum vertex cover? I can not find an example where the algorithm does not find a minimum vertex cover.

Comment: Why MathOverflow instead of Computer Science SE or CS Theory SE?

Comment: Given that finding a minimal vertex cover is NP-hard it's unlikely that your algorithm works. Depending on how you break ties in case there is more than one vertex of maximum degree, paths are counterexamples.

Comment: @FlorianLehner What do you mean with "paths are counterexamples"? Both in odd and even paths (i.e. paths with odd/even number of vertices) the algorithm finds a minimum vertex cover.

Comment: @MarioGiambarioli As I wrote, it depends on how you break ties: in $P_5$ there are three vertices of degree 2, perhaps the algorithm chooses the central vertex first. After that we are left with four vertices of degree 1, the algorithm could pick the endpoints of the original path. So we end up with a cover of 3 vertices, but the unique minimum cover consists of 2 vertices.

Comment: Just to clarify: by *cardinality*, you mean what's generally called *degree*? and when you remove a vertex, you also remove all the edges incident to that vertex?

Comment: @FlorianLehner You are right, in $P_{5}$ the algorithm does not work. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, with *cardinality* I mean *degree* (and this is the right word, I am sorry). When it removes a vertex, obviously all the edges incident to that vertex are removed because an edge is defined by a couple of vertices (a single vertex does not define an edge.